# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'company_name' in 'field list' when it's clearly there

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-insert, entity-relationship, error-code

I am developing an ERD Model in MySQL and I've been going through series of dropping schema and forward engineering again just to test an update in the modeling (I'm not conversant with synchronizing models just yet) but everything has been working just fine and okay.

I eventually used a MySQL/ODBC Connector to link Microsoft Access and make use of it as the Front-end. Everything still worked fine. Until recently and all of a sudden whenever I try to INSERT INTO the company table;

```
    INSERT INTO company(company_name, address, city_id, zip_code,
    country_code, kind_of_organization_id, number_of_employees, total_asset, 
    total_liability, registration_body_id, registration_date) 
VALUES
    ('Astro Planet Pictures', '90210 Rodeo Ave', 
    (SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE name = 'Athens'), 
    46543,
    (SELECT code FROM country WHERE country.name = 'Greece'), 
    (SELECT id FROM kind_of_organization WHERE name = 'Non Profit'), 
    45,
    393430.4, 98345.5, 
    (SELECT r.id FROM registration_body r, country c WHERE r.country_code = c.code AND c.name = 'Slovakia'), 
    '2020-01-04');
```

I get an error:

```
Error Code: 1054: Unknown column 'company_name' in 'field list'
```

A column "company_name" which has always been there from the start and never gave any issues during the INSERT INTO operation.

I cannot seem to identify what may be the cause of this problem or even trace a root, I need help as soon as possible.

I unsynced MS Access and MySQL just to make sure MySQL was acting alone in this instance.

I also changed the column name from 'company_name' to 'name' maybe an invisible character was at play even when I knew it wasn't the case. I don't have a lot of options at this point

For your references, this is the DDL of the COMPANY table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movie_production_companies`.`company` (
  `id` VARCHAR(144) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` VARCHAR(144) NOT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(115) NOT NULL,
  `zip_code` INT NOT NULL,
  `city_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `country_code` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  `kind_of_organization_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `number_of_employees` INT NOT NULL,
  `total_asset` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_liability` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `registration_body_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `registration_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `country_id_idx` (`country_code` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `city_id_idx` (`city_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `kind_of_organization_fk_idx` (`kind_of_organization_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `regulatory_body_fk_idx` (`registration_body_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `company_country_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`country_code`)
    REFERENCES `movie_production_companies`.`country` (`code`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `company_city_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`)
    REFERENCES `movie_production_companies`.`city` (`city_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `company_kind_of_organization_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`kind_of_organization_id`)
    REFERENCES `movie_production_companies`.`kind_of_organization` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `company_regulatory_body_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`registration_body_id`)
    REFERENCES `movie_production_companies`.`registration_body` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And I restored the only Trigger associated with the COMPANY table to original format but nothing

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `movie_production_companies`.`company_BEFORE_INSERT_pk_maker` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `company` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE space_count INT;
    
    SET space_count = LENGTH(company_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(company_name, ' ', ''));
    
    IF space_count = 0 THEN
        SET NEW.id =  CONCAT(
            NEW.country_code, '-', 
            UPPER(LEFT(NEW.company_name, 3)), '-',
            FLOOR(100000 + RAND() * 900000)
        );
    ELSEIF space_count = 1 THEN
        SET NEW.id = CONCAT(
            NEW.country_code, '-', 
            UPPER(LEFT(NEW.company_name, 1)), 
            UPPER(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.company_name, ' ', -1), 2)),
            FLOOR(100000 + RAND() * 900000)
        );
    ELSE
        SET NEW.id = CONCAT(
        NEW.country_code, '-', 
        UPPER(LEFT(NEW.company_name, 1)), 
        UPPER(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.company_name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 1)),
        UPPER(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.company_name, ' ', 3), ' ', -1), 1)),
        FLOOR(100000 + RAND() * 900000)
        );
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Images of code don't help much. Can you copy-and-paste the text instead? (When editing, highlight the code and click `{}`.)

Comment: Do you have any triggers on company? If there are could they be throwing the error?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes i have a trigger that generates an ID for the companies based on certain conditions. This Trigger has always worked but I made some changes to it recently and it has not worked since. I'm going to change it back to what it used to be when it worked and get back to you with an update.

Comment: @jarlh thank you i just edited the post and added the codes

Comment: Once you've fixed the trigger, if you still have an issue, please update your question with the full DDL for the COMPANY table, including any keys/constraints/etc

Comment: @NickW thank you i just updated the question with the DDL and yes the problem persisted even after restoring the trigger to what worked in the past

Comment: @P.Salmon the problem persisted even after restoring an older version of the trigger. maybe the problem is not concerning triggers?

Comment: If you drop the trigger completely do you still get the issue? That would at least prove whether it is the code being run by the insert or by the trigger that is causing the issue

Comment: In the trigger I think you need to use `NEW.company_name` or `OLD.company_name`, not just `company_name` by itself. You do that correctly for all the other columns.

Comment: @Barmar you're right. i'll replace the `company_name` where necessary with `NEW.company_name`. thanks for noticing that.

Comment: @NickW I'm going to try that. be right back